# Jquery form being submitted twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a really strange problem. My Jquery based form appears to be submitting its self twice.

It only happens when I use the following code to submit my form:

```
<button class="btn dark"><i id="transfer-spin" class="fa fa-cog"></i> Transfer...</button>
```

When I use the following, I do not get the double submit:

```
<input type="submit" value="Transfer" class="btn btn-success dark" id="transfer-button"/>
```

Here is the code in context:

**FORM:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal hidden" id="transfer-form" novalidate>
    <fieldset>
               <div class="control-group">
               <div>&nbsp;</div>
               <div class="controls">
               <button class="btn dark"><i id="transfer-spin" class="fa fa-cog"></i> Transfer...</button>
            </div>
        </div>

      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

**And the JQuery code:**

```
 $('#transfer-form').submit(function()
    {
       event.preventDefault();

       //run some error checks

       if (messageArray.length !== 0)
        {
           //Return errors
        } else {
            $('#transfer-button').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#transfer-spin').addClass('fa-spin');

            var url ='/api/transfer';

            $.ajax({
                //Do the ajax call...
```

Comment: Why don't you give button type='submit'?

Comment: @depperm The [default `type` for buttons _is_ `submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type).  When I first saw this, I thought it was going to be a case of the button needing to be changed to not be `type="submit"`, but having read it all, I'm not sure what's causing a double submit.

Comment: I believe that different browsers have different defaults, "Always specify the type attribute for the <button> element. Different browsers may use different default types for the <button> element." from http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp

Comment: w3schools isn't the _best_ source of info on these matters...

Comment: @depperm [Here's the actual HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-button-type) that confirms the default is submit.  If different browers _do_ have different default types, the browser has a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and help. I left out the 'event' as a parameter. All working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `event` as parameter in `submit`:

```
$('#transfer-form').submit(function(event)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to specify the event variable in the function, with that you can prevent default behavior.

```
$('#transfer-form').submit(function(event)
{
   event.preventDefault(); 
   ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your submit function needs to receive the event object

function (event) {
...